# Remove default browser scrollbar and add a new scrollbar with transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, scrollbar

I'm working on my website using WordPress and needed to add a custom scrollbar and increase the thumb width on hover like this example: [bit.ly/3IPxa1X](https://www.stereo.ca/).
But I can't achieve that since the scrollbar width is already set to 10px, and when I make the scrollbar transparent I get a white background.

[image: image of scrollbar]

So after I checked the website I think they didn't customize the default browser scrollbar. Instead, they've added a new scrollbar inside the page so the scrollbar could be transparent and they could control the thumb width on hover.

I did ask ChatGPT to help me out but it gave me this code, which didn't work as well:

```js
// Get scrollbar and content elements
const customScrollbar = document.getElementById('custom-scrollbar');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

// Calculate scrollbar thumb height based on content height
const scrollbarHeight = customScrollbar.clientHeight;
const contentHeight = content.scrollHeight;
const thumbHeight = scrollbarHeight * (scrollbarHeight / contentHeight);

// Set scrollbar thumb height
document.getElementById('scrollbar-thumb').style.height = thumbHeight + 'px';

// Add event listener to update thumb position on scroll
content.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const scrollTop = content.scrollTop;
  const thumbTop = scrollTop * (scrollbarHeight / contentHeight);
  document.getElementById('scrollbar-thumb').style.top = thumbTop + 'px';
});
```

```css
/* Hide default browser scrollbar */
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style custom scrollbar */
#custom-scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#scrollbar-thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

/* Style scrollbar thumb on hover */
#scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  width: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <aside id="custom-scrollbar">
    <div id="scrollbar-thumb"></div>
  </aside>
  <div id="content">
    <!-- your website content here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

ChatGPT Explanation:

First, we add a  tag with an id of "custom-scrollbar" to create our custom scrollbar. We also add a  with an id of "scrollbar-thumb" to represent the scrollbar thumb.

In the CSS code, we hide the default browser scrollbar by setting the "overflow" property of the body element to "hidden". We then style the custom scrollbar by setting its position to "fixed", its height to "100%", and its width to "10px". We also give it a background color of "#f5f5f5" and a z-index of 9999 to ensure it appears on top of other elements.

Next, we style the scrollbar thumb by setting its position to "absolute", its top and left positions to "0", its width to "100%", and its background color to "#888". We also give it a border-radius of 5px and a transition effect of 0.2s ease-in-out for the width property to create a smooth hover effect. We then add a :hover pseudo-class to increase the width of the scrollbar thumb to 12px when the user hovers over it.

We first get the custom scrollbar and content elements in the JavaScript code using their respective ids. We then calculate the scrollbar thumb height based on the height of the custom scrollbar and the content using the clientHeight and scrollHeight properties, respectively. We set the height of the scrollbar thumb accordingly.

We then add an event listener to the content element to update the position of the scrollbar thumb when the user scrolls. We get the current scroll position using the scrollTop property, calculate the new position of the scrollbar thumb utilising the ratio of the scroll position to the content height, and update the top position.

Comment: Do you want to make it from scratch or is it okay if you use a JavScript library? I think this library https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/ is quite suitable for what you want to achieve. If it's okay to use library, I can help you create a sample code how to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my projects, I wanted to do the same thing and accomplished it with this code. Here is the sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxydem9n/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: block;
  width: 7px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
    
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
  background: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 1000px; background-color: black"></div>
```

Here in this example "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb" is the main scroll which you can change the color border and even change it on hover, "::-webkit-scrollbar-track" is the whole scroll section which you want to be transparent. The thing is that in some browsers this might not work and the scroll section's background won't be visible, in that case, you can just change it and put the color of your main section or body, or even an image. The thing is that in the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxydem9n/
The scrolling background is not white, but here it still shows white. Try this with your custom scroll bar and let me know if this helped you or not.